# Underscore.js - xyz is not defined (8 out of range 5)

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, tastypie, marionette

I am getting a very strange error on one part of my site, which is built with backbone.js, backbone.marionette. I am using underscore.js for templates and tastypie for the REST framework.

Firebug outputs a "ReferenceError: xyz (where <%= xyz %> in the underscore template) is not defined". (8 out of range 5).

When I trace this back to the underscore-min.js file, it does not have 8 lines, as it's a min file. That's to be expected.

However, I'm suspecting a syntax error instead, as manual manipulation of the variables in the console works fine.

I can manually define a **name** model fetch from the REST framework, and render it in its view. I can even output it to the front end properly with MyApp.testSection.show("the rendered view") without any issues.

I am suspecting something wrong in the syntax either within the NameView template: _.template(...) section or MyApp.addInitializer

**CODE BELOW**

```
Name = TastypieModel.extend({

    urlRoot:'/api/v1/names/Calvin'

});

//returns an array {'name':'Calvin', 'age':32, etc....}

NameView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    model: Name,
    template: _.template("<h1>My name is <%= name %></h1>"),
    tagName: 'p',

    initialize: function(){
        this.bindTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    }
});

MyApp.addInitializer(function(options){

    var name = new Name();

    name.fetch();

    var nameview = new NameView ({
        model: name
    });


    MyApp.testSection.show(nameview);

});
```

Comment: do the job of creating and showing your view inside the success callback of fetch method.Since its a async call it might be creating problems

Comment: Marionette uses underscore as default for compiling your templates.So u can avoid doing it.

Comment: Your template declaration looks fine. Where is your render method? And what does testSection.show() do? In your render method, make sure your model is calling .toJSON() when it's passed into the template, as Backbone model attributes are actually stored in model.attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by your fetch of the data.

`model.fetch()` is an asynchronous operation, but your code doesn't account for this. You're rendering the view with a model that has not data because the rendering happens immediately after calling `fetch` instead of waiting for the model to be fetched.

```
MyApp.addInitializer(function(options){

    var name = new Name();

    var fetched = name.fetch();

    // wait for the model to be fetched
    $.when(fetched).then(function(){

      var nameview = new NameView ({
        model: name
      });

      MyApp.testSection.show(nameview);

    });

});
```

Comment: Would this be possible using Marionette.async? There is other information that I would like to display on a single-page app, which I'd like to render "live" as changes occur.

Comment: don't use marionette.async. it's out of date and not maintained anymore. what you want is just event handlers on the model. listen to the "change" events and update the DOM as needed.

Comment: Thanks! I love Marionette btw.